# How do I merge WooCommerce categories with the same name?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I have duplicate product categories - they share the same name but different slugs eg., The category 'Adhesives' has a slug of "adhesives" but since updating my products via CSV import, there is now also a category named "Adhesives" with slug of "adhesives-2" which the updated products have been moved to.

I am aware plugins exist which allow you to do this per category but I have over 1500 categories.

Is there a MySQL query that will merge all categories with the same name (disregarding the slugs)? And/or another method of doing this?

Thanks in advance, Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Term Management](https://wordpress.org/plugins/term-management-tools/) plugin. You can use it to bulk merge your duplicate categories into one. Follow these steps:

1. Install and activate the plugin.
2. Go to **Posts > Categories**.
3. Select the categories that you want to merge. Then select the merge
   option from the bulk option.
4. Type the name to which you want to merge these categories. Finally,
   click on the **Apply** button.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am aware plugins like this exist but I have over 1500 categories so this isn't a viable option.